# Handle exception in reactive streams and return value from previous call

Tags: java, exception, reactive-programming, reactor

I'm having some trouble with reactive streams and based on my code below, the return value of the function should be the value created by the call to `myServiceConnector.createSummary(request)`, whether or not the following call to `otherService.postDetails(summary, details, item)` throws an exception or not. If it throws an exception I just want to do some logging and otherwise ignore it.

```
public Mono<Summary> createSummary(final Details details, String authorisation)
{
    return myService.doSomething(details.getItemId(), authorisation)
                       .zipWhen(item -> Mono.just(convertToMyRequest(item, details, myServiceConfig.getBaseRedirectUrl())))
                       .flatMap(tuple -> {
                           MyItem item = tuple.getT1();
                           OrderRequest request = tuple.getT2();
                           return myServiceConnector.createSummary(request)
                                                       .doOnSuccess(summary -> otherService.postDetails(summary, details, item)
                                                                                                            .onErrorContinue((o,i) -> {
                                                                                                                // Log error
                                                                                                            }));

                       });
}
```

Currently it seems that the `onErrorContinue` call is not called (I am forcing an exception to be thrown by `otherService.postDetails(summary, details, item)` in my test). I have also tried `onErrorResume` which was called but the exception was still thrown so I got no `Summary` object returned. Not sure if I have my error handling in the right place.

Updating to include test code below:

```
@Test
public void returnSummaryWhenOtherServiceFails()
{
    Details details = Details.builder()
                             .itemId(ITEM_ID)
                             .build();

    when(myServiceConfig.getBaseRedirectUrl()).thenReturn(BASE_REDIRECT_URL);
    when(myService.doSomething(ITEM_ID, AUTH_STRING)).thenReturn(Mono.just(ITEM));
    when(myServiceConnector.createSummary(any())).thenReturn(SUMMARY);
    when(otherService.postDetails(any(), any(), any())).thenThrow(WebClientResponseException.class);

    summaryService.createSummary(details, AUTH_STRING).block();
    
    verify(myServiceConnector).createSummary(any());
}
```

The test fails due to:

`org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException`

Comment: the otherService call has no subscriber because it is called in a side-effect operator, you should either explicitly subscribe or use some other operator instead of doOnSuccess

Comment: regarding the error handling, please, also share your test code, especially the part where you mock otherService, I suspect that is not implemented idiomatically

Comment: @MartinTarjányi I have added the test code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `otherService.postDetails` in background and don't care about its result then you can do it like this:

```
otherService.postDetails(...).subscribe()
```

or

```
otherService.postDetails(...).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic()).subscribe()
```

it's depended on your code.

Or you can change your code like this:

```
myServiceConnector.createSummary(request)
.flatMap(summary -> otherService.postDetails(summary, details, item)
    .onErrorContinue(...)
)
```

it will run `createSummary` and then `postDetails` and if `postDetails` fails then `onErrorContinue` will be triggered.